# Can cube.js be used to access raw data as well as aggregated data?

Tags: cube.js

For example, if I have a Postgres table with columns for sensor_id, temperature and time_recorded , would I still be able to generate a chart that shows temperature (y) over time (x) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible with 2 steps:

1. defining a [data schema](https://cube.dev/docs/schema/getting-started) for that table.
2. define a [query to get data](https://cube.dev/docs/query-format#top) from that data schema.

after retrieving the data you can feed it to the chart library of your choice.